# SDL2 modifying pixels

Tags: c++, sdl, pixel

I want to modify single pixels with SDL2 and I don't want to do it with surfaces.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
// Create a texture for drawing
SDL_Texture *m_pDrawing = SDL_CreateTexture(m_pRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 1024, 768);

// Create a pixelbuffer
Uint32 *m_pPixels = (Uint32 *) malloc(1024*768*sizeof(Uint32));

// Set a single pixel to red
m_pPixels[1600] = 0xFF0000FF;

// Update the texture with created pixelbuffer
SDL_UpdateTexture(m_pDrawing, NULL, m_pPixels, 1024*sizeof(Uint32));

// Copy texture to render target
SDL_RenderCopy(m_pRenderer, m_pDrawing, NULL, NULL);
```

If it is rendered then with SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer) nothing appears on screen. 
[Here](http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#If_your_game_just_wants_to_get_fully-rendered_frames_to_the_screen) they explained that you could either use "surface->pixels, or a malloc()'d buffer". So, what's wrong?

Edit:
In the end it was just my m_pRenderer which was defined after the SDL_CreateTexture call.
Everything works fine now and I fixed the small bug in the buffer allocation, so this code should be working.

Comment: do you get any errors when calling [SDL_UpdateTexture](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture). Can you load a texture from BMP or something? If no, check out the example in this [page](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy). Can you try making a huge area of pixels red to see maybe the pixel isn't seen in a cloud of black pixels?

Comment: Oh I should have checked for errors before... It always gives an "Invalid Texture" error. Something is wrong with m_pDrawing then.

Comment: If `SDL_UpdateTexture` gives invalid texture that means you get an error in `SDL_CreateTexture` and return 0, according to [docs](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture). So check out the error for that one also.

Comment: I checked SDL_CreateTexture for errors and got "Invalid Renderer". Then I searched m_pRenderer and saw that it was defined after calling the SDL_CreateTexture. Well, that's embarrassing... Everything works fine now. Thanks anyway for leading me to my stupid fault :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but it's a bug:

```
Uint32 *m_pPixels = (Uint32 *) malloc(1024*768);
```

You need a `* sizeof(Uint32)` in there, if you want to allocate enough data to represent the pixels in your surface:

```
Uint32 *m_pPixels = (Uint32 *) malloc(1024*768*sizeof(Uint32));
```

(And if this is C, you don't need the cast.)

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, I forgot about that. But it didn't fix the problem. I don't even know if you can do it like that, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "I don't even know if you can do it like that". (You *will* need the sizeof(Uint32), as `SDL_UpdateTexture` will want to read width*height*size-of-a-pixel bytes.) Also, as others mentioned, you should update your question to reflect whether or not `SDL_UpdateText` returns an error or not.